# Views: add (link to file field) to image field

Tags: 7, views, navigation, tokens, files

In D7, I have an *event* content type containing an *image* field ("Featured image") and a *file* field ("Document"). I have a view of events containing documents, and would like to wrap a link around the image, leading to the document. Here's a [sample link](http://kpuc.org/sites/default/files/doc/easter_6c_2016.pdf).

**How can I rewrite the image (or use another technique) to get the desired link around the image?** Looking at available tokens (I did add a second, hidden Document field above the image to define tokens), nothing seems suitable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First add the "Content:File" field
- Check "Exclude from display" (hidden)
- Under "Formatter" select "URL to file"
- Then add your Image field and uncheck "Link this field to the original piece of content" or something similar
- Click on "Rewrite Results" and check "Output this field as a link"
- In the "Link path" textbox add "Replacement Pattern" from the file field ([field_file] == Content: File, for example)

Comment: Thank you! I had used a similar method, but was rewriting the field output and it left me feeling dirty… I knew there was a more neutral way to tell Drupal about the link URL without interfering with its markup rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write

['imag-tag']

in view select "Global custom" field.